# Extract text from a PDF in Railo

Tags: pdf, indexing, lucene, cfml, railo

Just taking over coding a Railo site (Railo 3.3.4.003) and I want to index a large number of PDFs. However, cfindex only seems to index text docs. I see there is `<cfpdf action="extracttext">`, but apparently this is not supported in Railo. Can anyone confirm or otherwise? If not is the best option org.apache.pdfbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFBox will certainly do the job. There's an old version included in the Railo class path, but I found it to be buggy. Instead I would use [JavaLoader](https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader) to load the latest version.

**pdfTextExtractor.cfc**

```
/* The latest pre-built standalone PDFBox jar file and the javaloader package are assumed to be in the same folder as the following component */
component{

    function init( javaLoaderPath="javaloader.JavaLoader" ){
        if( !server.KeyExists( "_pdfBoxLoader" ) ){
            var paths=[];
            paths.append( GetDirectoryFromPath( GetCurrentTemplatePath() ) & "pdfbox-app-1.8.11.jar" );
            server._pdfBoxLoader=New "#javaLoaderPath#"( paths );
        }
        variables.reader=server._pdfBoxLoader.create( "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument" );
        variables.stripper=server._pdfBoxLoader.create( "org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper" );
        return this;
    }

    string function extractText( required string pdfPath, numeric startPage=0, numeric endPage=0 ){
        if( Val( startPage ) )
            stripper.setStartPage( startPage );
        if( Val( endPage ) )
            stripper.setEndPage( endPage );
        var pdf=reader.load( pdfPath );
        var text=stripper.getText( pdf );
        reader.close();
        return text;
    }

}
```

See http://blog.simplicityweb.co.uk/94/migrating-from-coldfusion-to-railo-part-7-pdfs for more detail.

The above will also work with [Lucee](http://lucee.org/), Railo's successor, to which I'd strongly advise migrating.

Comment: Thanks CFSimplicity, will give that a go

Comment: CfSimplicity, I am using PDFBox 1.8.11, and an getting the following error: "The requested class 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument' could not be found in the loaded jars/directories." AND "The requested class 'org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper' could not be found in the loaded jars/directories." What am I doing wrong?